# I need help resetting the DEFAULT settings for ActiveX and Flash Player

Tags: flash, security

When I start my web browser and I want to view a website or view something on a Flash Player I get this message:

> Your Security settings do not allow websites to use ActiveX controls installed on your computer. This page may not display correctly. click here for options.

or I get this:

> If this site does not load, click here to install Flash.

Can someone help me reset my settings so I don't have this problem anymore?

Answer (score 0):

i take it you are using Internet Explorer? Get a better browser like firefox if you are.

Comment: i wasnt trying to be rude, i was serious, internet explorer has different settings in some of their version that requires user interaction before running swf context.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537508(VS.85).aspx